# How to find outliers in R for MDS?

Tags: r

I'm making a MDS plot with Salary and WAR data from baseball players. I have attached it here. Because there are so many data points I just want to label the Baseball Player names for the outlier data points. Any idea on how to do so?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, first it depends on the method you want to detect the outliers. I create a reproducible example, since you did not provide a dataset. I'm using the `mtcars` dataset, which is a regular dataset already implemented in R.

For outlier detection I'm using the cooks distance (you can check about that in a post [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/353380/identifying-outliers-in-the-data/353411#353411))

First i set up the data and calculating the cooks distance (cooksd) with `cooks.distance` from stats between the variables `hp` and `sec`

```
df<-cbind( mtcars[,c("hp", "qsec")], cooks.distance(lm(mtcars$hp~mtcars$qsec)))
names(df)[3]<-"cooksd"


plot(cooks.distance(lm(mtcars$hp~mtcars$qsec)))
```

[image: cookds]

We see, that we got two outliers. I'm using the threshold of `4*mean(cooksd)` and labeling those in my dataset with following loop. Those are considered as outliers.

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)){
if (df$cooksd[i] > 4* mean(df$cooksd)){
  df$outlier[i] =1
}else {df$outlier[i]=0}
}
```

Last step is to plot the values and only give a label to those, which are above the threshold. I'm using here the `row.names`, but you can also use any column, just filter it as the other datapoints.

```
plot(df$hp, df$qsec,
     text(df[df$outlier==1,"hp"], df[df$outlier==1,"qsec"], row.names(df[df$outlier == 1,]), cex=0.6, pos=4, col="red") )
```

[image: plot with outlier labels]

A huge problem with outlier detection is, there are different methods and for every case the interpretation must be adjusted. Which method you want to use or which threshold, won't be answered here, since it's  more a discussion for stackexchange. You can use cooksd, stdev or anything you seem it is the most useful. But the solution stays the same:

1. use your method to find the outliers
2. label them in your dataset
3. just implement the text in your plot, which you labelled.

For your three clusters, you just have to do a `lm` modell for every cluster, label the outliers and then join all three results.